# Why can't I post anything in Super User?

Tags: support, post-ban

Why I can not post any question in Super User?  My account was suspended temporarily due to the low contributions, but now it should be expired, why I still can't post a question?

Comment: I can honestly just recommend you—if you manage to lift your ban—to ask questions about actual problems that you're facing, not just for the sake of asking questions. A lot of your recent posts seem a little contrived and hardly based on any issue somebody would face in real life.

Answer (score 9):

I'm Tim Post - a community manager for Stack Exchange.

Your account is not suspended, however due to the quality of your previous questions, you have been blocked from asking or answering questions until you've improved the quality of your previous contributions.

The blocks were automatically triggered by the system, due to the number of questions you've asked and answers you've posted that have been down voted or not voted on at all. Deleted posts of either type are also taken into consideration.

At this point, all I can recommend is reading the advice in the [link you were given](http://goo.gl/C1Kwu) and working to improve your past content. I'll be honest, it's going to take a good bit of work on your part before you're able to post again. The system needs to know that you've improved the quality of your posts by the amount of up votes that they receive. Then, and only then will the blocks be lifted.

If you have any further questions, please feel free to [contact us directly](https://meta.superuser.com/help/quality-blocks), we'd rather not discuss the specifics of your account, or any other account publicly in any more detail than we've already gone into here.

Comment: I have tried and couldn't contact you directly from the link you gave me, pls advise and btw, what kinda of site is this 'meta'superuser.

Comment: @frog please e-mail `team@stackexchange.com` directly then. Meta is a site where we talk about Super User itself, such as what should be on topic, question closings that may need review, general support and other things related to the community itself.

Answer (score 5):

Suspensions are a manual action by a moderator, restrict all actions on the site, and typically last from a day to a year. [Read more about what suspensions are intended for here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). Your suspension has been lifted, so this isn't the reason you cannot ask questions.

---

From your description, it looks like you're getting the following message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

This is an automatic restriction placed on your account. There is nothing we moderators on Super User can do about this. [More information is available in the linked MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

---

It's possible that the action that caused a moderator to suspend you also resulted in your questions no longer getting accepted. Moderators don't have access to information about question or answer restrictions on your account.